# How do I have different web applications share same classloader?

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader, contextclassloader

We have a suite of applications.  As it is now, each application can be deployed individually, or in any combination.  The problem is that each of the wars is constructed with its own copy of libraries.  Many (LOTS) of which are duplicated in each war.

I know if we throw the libs in the common area of Tomcat, they can all share those resources.  However, is there a way to have each application, on start, check to see if another application already loaded the classes its trying to load and if another application has, use those instead of re-loading its own version?

Comment: Wouldn't you encounter a problem if those application are trying to access different versions of this class ?

Comment: get more memory, it's a lot less trouble than what you're thinking of. Do you want to create a situation where you can't upgrade one of these without upgrading all of them?

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope That isn't a risk in the way we deploy. NathanHughes As it is now, they all share from the same pom file, so they already are tied when being upgraded.